# Find a value $c$ such that $\left\|\begin{pmatrix} x^2 - y^2\\2xy \end{pmatrix}\right\| \leq |c|\left\|\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}\right\|$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra

This is part of a larger problem where I am trying to find the derivative of a vector valued function. I feel like I'm missing something simple. NOTE: $c$ can be a function of $x$ and $y$.

Comment: Are $x,y$ reals, and is $\|\cdot\|$ the euclidean norm?

Comment: Yes, though choice of norm shouldn't change the answer.

Comment: Obviously false except for $\|(x,y)\|$ small.

Comment: It doesn't seem like you can get it - set $y=0$ and you'll have $|x|^2\leq |cx|$, which is not true for $|x|>|c|$.

Comment: As people are saying above, it is false. Choice of norm wouldn't affect the existence of such a  $c$; it would however change the value of $c$.

Comment: With $c=c(x,y)$ is trivial and uninteresting.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews If $c$ = $x$ then wouldn't it still be satisfied. Note: $c$ is a function of $x$ and $y$ ...perhaps I chose a poor letter for my variable.

Comment: Sigh, really, $c$ is a function? First, that was not stated in your problem, and second $c$ is almost always a *c*onstant in this sort of question, or at least constant relative to some variable, and third, the problem is trivial if you want a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We compute

$$(x^2 - y^2)^2 + (2xy)^2 = x^{4} - 2x^{2}y^{2}+ y^{4} + 4x^{2}y^{2} = x^{4} + 2x^2 y^2 + y^4 = (x^2 + y^2)^2$$

Hence

$$\sqrt{(x^2 - y^2)^2 + (2xy)^2} = \sqrt{(x^2 + y^2)^2} = x^2 + y^2$$

We are trying to find $c$ for which

$$ (x^2 + y^2) \leq c \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}$$

If we let $z = x^2 + y^2$ we obtain

$$ z \leq c \sqrt{z}$$

Does this seem possible?

Comment: If $c=\sqrt z$.

Comment: $\sqrt{z}$ is not constant.

Comment: Yes but user393e said that: "NOTE: $c$ can be a function of $x$ and $y$."

Comment: That was added later and makes the problem trivial.

Answer (score 1):

If you think about where your quadratic function comes from, it is the representation of $z=(x+iy)^2 = (x^2-y^2)+i(2xy)$ where $z=x+iy$. So you want to be considering
$$|z^2| = |z|^2.$$
That is, your "constant" needs to be $|z|$.

Answer (score 1):

If $c$ is allowed to be a function of $x,y$ as is stated in the comments then the following would work.

In polar coordiantes the following:
$$\left\|\begin{pmatrix} x^2 - y^2\\2xy \end{pmatrix}\right\| \leq |c|\left\|\begin{pmatrix} x\\y \end{pmatrix}\right\|$$
is:
$$x=r\cos(\theta),\quad y=r\sin(\theta)$$
$$\left\|\begin{pmatrix} r^2\cos(2\theta)\\r^2\sin(2\theta)\end{pmatrix}\right\| \leq |c|\left\|\begin{pmatrix} r\cos(\theta)\\r\sin(\theta) \end{pmatrix}\right\|$$
$$r^2 \leq |c|r$$
so I guess choose $$c=kr=k\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$$
for any constant $k\ge 1$ and with equality holding only for $k=1$.

Perhaps the condition is expected to hold over some finite circle of radius $r$  (open set) rather than all of space, in which case you can chose any constant $c\ge r$, and it need not be a function of $x,y$.